# Как сделать mp3 проигрыватель для сайта на php?

Tags: php, html, css, mp3

Я знаю, что по правилам форума надо приводить пример того, чего не получается, но на этот вопрос я  даже не могу найти ответа.

Comment: На чистом php проигрыватель не сделать!

Comment: Сам php имеет мало отношения к сути вопроса. Музыка будет проигрываться на клиенте (в браузере), поэтому речь надо вести о программировании клиентской части: js, flash, html5.

Answer (score 2):

Может тогда сначала с плеерами на javascript разберетесь, благо на том же jQuery плагинов хватает:

[Один из них](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-mp3-player-plugin-jplayer/) Я когда-то занимался им, вроде все работало, да и сейчас должно.

Comment: попробую, но всё равно помогите кто нить ещё!

Comment: по моему это все на флеш заморочено, ну и html5.

Comment: jplayer вполне годный плеер. Берите и пользуйтесь.